# Reversing string and toggle lower-upper-case

Tags: java

I need to write an application which takes a String as input. After processing, it should print out the string reversed, and all characters switched from lower to uppercase and vise versa. I want to achieve this using a `StringBuilder`.

Sample run:
Input: Hello Human
Output: NAMUh OLLEh

Comment: If it's homework, please tag it with the homework-tag.

Comment: I get paid per minute for doing homework, let me know if you can afford my services. :)

Comment: ?raf os deirt ev'uoy tahw tsoP

Comment: The StringBuilder class has some methods you may find useful.

Comment: [Homework] "Questions regarding homework assignments are welcome as long as they are asked honestly, explain the problem, and show sufficient effort." or any questions for that matter need to show some attempt

Comment: Nice Raoul +1 but the p should be lower case with the rest upper, for extra credit make the question mark upside down.

Comment: i dont know if its good..but i know its not..

Answer (score 2):

Here is a straight forward and simple way of solving the problem:

1. Read user input using for instance the [`Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class. and the `nextLine()` method. (Construct the `Scanner` by giving it `System.in` as argument.)
2. Create a `StringBuilder`.
3. Fetch the array of characters from the input string, using for instance [`input.toCharArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29)
4. Reverse the array with `Arrays.asList` and `Collections.reverse`

   ```
   Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(yourCharArray));
   ```
5. Loop through the list using for instance a for-each loop.

   ```
   for (Character c : yourCharArray) {
       ...
   }
   ```
6. For each character, check if `c.isUpperCase` (if so append `c.toLowerCase()`) else append `c.toUpperCase()`.

(An alternative approach would be to give the StringBuilder the input-string as argument, and manipulate the string in-place using the `reverse`, `charAt` and `setCharAt` methods.)

Comment: StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0 ; i<s.length() ; i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if(i!=0&&Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
        result.append(' ');
    }
    result.append(c);

Comment: @aioobe, why couldn't you just point to `StringBuilder.reverse()` method instead?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman. That's a good point. I added it (sort of) as a final remark. This was just the first solution that came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

To reverse a String use `String reverse = new StringBuffer(YourString).reverse().toString();`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [StringBuilder.reverse](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29) and [Character.toLowerCase](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase%28char%29)/[Character.toUpperCase](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28char%29)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an "elite" 3-line solution:

```
    StringBuffer buffy = new StringBuffer("!GNIzA Ma").reverse();
    for (int i = 0; i < buffy.length(); i++)
        buffy.setCharAt(i, Character.isLetter(buffy.charAt(i)) ? (char) (buffy.charAt(i) ^ 32) : buffy.charAt(i));

    System.out.println(buffy); // "Am aZing!"
```

This works because the xor `^` with `32` (or `0x20`) toggles the 3rd bit of the byte which changes upper to lower and visa versa. This toggling only works for letters of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
      `function toggleCase(text){
         let toggledString='';
         for(let i=0;i<text.length;i++){
            if(text[i]==text[i].toUpperCase())
               toggledString+=text[i].toLowerCase();
            else if(text[i]==text[i].toLowerCase())
                    toggledString+=text[i].toUpperCase();
           }
         return toggledString;
       }`
```

Comment: You should describe your solution. Also you have extra ` characters at the beginning and end of your code snippet.